# how to set an back ground color for an .rpt reports in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i have report which is of an .rpt  report. i need to set the background color for the  report  but still by default it is showing  me the  white color

```
rptReportViewer.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromKnownColor(selectedKnownColor);
```

Is there any other way i can define my  background color for the  reports[.rpt]

Thank  you.

Comment: What reporting tool are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also pass the desired color to the report as a parameter.  Then use the parameter to set the report's background

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Crystal Reports, which it appears that you are see this, "[Modifying the Background Color of the Report.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227526.aspx)"

For Microsoft Reporting Services:
This will set your **ReportViewer** back color to the selectedKnowColor, not the report itself. Your report probably covers most of the ReportViewer. If you have any of the ReportViewer visible then you should see it's back color change.

For either case make sure your selectedKnowColor isn't white.